# Angular 5 - Making HTTP PUT request from service rather than component causes CORS error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upload a file via a simple PUT request, and when the block of code that makes the request is inside a **component**, it uploads fine - no errors. When the block of code is in a **service**, however, the PUT turns into an OPTIONS request, and I get this error:

```
Failed to load <MY-URL>: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is baffling because the request code is literally identical. This is how I make the request:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url, file, {
  reportProgress: true,
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
});

this.http.request(req).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  ...
});
```

Here's what Chrome shows for the request headers of a successful request:

```
:authority:storage.googleapis.com
:method:PUT
:path:<MY-URL>
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length:37349
content-type:image/jpeg
origin:http://localhost:4200
referer:http://localhost:4200/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CIu2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCI2aygEI+pzKAQipncoBCKijygE=
```

and an unsuccessful one:

```
:authority:storage.googleapis.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:<MY-URL>
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers:content-type
access-control-request-method:PUT
origin:http://localhost:4200
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CIu2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCI2aygEI+pzKAQipncoBCKijygE=
```

Just to reiterate, the same block of code works fine in a component and throws a CORS error from a service.

EDIT: Response headers for unsuccessful request:

```
alt-svc:hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
cache-control:private, max-age=0
content-length:0
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 18 Feb 2018 08:33:31 GMT
expires:Sun, 18 Feb 2018 08:33:31 GMT
server:UploadServer
status:200
x-guploader-uploadid:AEnB2Uqd39siSJ9623Ocg-RMxfeLerhCmz17poAgEmFWYq2sztl23DBQNznISqtWA_TFnQmE7Dkq0x1sgNTTDkUk0SJ574eAPw
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable CORS in your cloud storage account: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: I stated multiple times that the request works when made from a component. CORS is already enabled.

Comment: Can you add the response headers that you're getting from that OPTIONS preflight request then please?

Comment: Added above. Compared to the response headers of a successful request, the unsuccessful request response is missing all of the 'access-control' headers.

Comment: Could it be that your service is using the old Http class, not HttpClient?

Comment: No, definitely using the new one. With that said, I've been doing some testing, and it looks like only one particular service is affected - I whipped up a barebones service with nothing but the upload code, called it from the component, and it worked. Still don't know what's wrong with the original service though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a huge idiot. The pre-signed URL I was trying to upload to in the 'cursed' service was being generated with a misspelled bucket name, so of course it wasn't getting the right CORS headers, because it wasn't even hitting the bucket's URL.